# SQL Capitalize first letter except 3 letter words

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I need an SQL statement (function) to capitalize the first letter of each word the other characters have to be lower    case. The part that i don't know how to do it is that i need to keep the structure of 3 letter words

Words can be like :

DOT FOODS ,
dot foods ,
CANADA COMPANY INC ,
CANADA COMPANY inc ,

Expected :

DOT Foods ,
dot Foods ,
Canada Company INC ,
Canada Company inc ,

With this function i get everything i need except the last part with the 3 words :

```
CREATE FUNCTION CAP(@String VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @Position INT;

      SELECT @String = STUFF(Lower(@String), 1, 1, UPPER(LEFT(@String, 1)))
                       COLLATE
                              Latin1_General_Bin,
             @Position = PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z''][a-z]%',
                         @String COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin);

      WHILE @Position > 0
        SELECT @String = STUFF(@String, @Position, 2, UPPER(
                                             Substring(@String, @Position, 2)))
                                                    COLLATE
                                                    Latin1_General_Bin,
               @Position = PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z''][a-z]%',
                           @String COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin);

      RETURN @String;
  END;
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: As you've already discovered from your current function, T-SQL is a *really* bad language to have to do this in, since its string processing capabilities are, in a word, rubbish. If at all possible, consider moving this step to however you do ETL/data ingestion, or to the presentation layer if it's only for display purposes.

Comment: Currently using :  SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18338.0

Comment: @Ace Management Studio is just an IDE, not the actual SQL Server. Do `@@version` and show that result

Comment: The version of SSMS you are using doesn't tell us what version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: My bad guys : Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Nov  8 2022 12:27:23   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation

Comment: Then you're using Azure SQL Database, *not* SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're on Azure SQL Database you have access to `STRING_SPLIT`'s new parameter, *ordinal*. This means you can therefore *split* the string at each white space (`' '`) and have the ordinal position return. Then you can re-aggregate the string using the `ordinal` column to maintain the order, and use a `CASE` expression to check the length of the value; if it's 3 (or fewer) characters leave it as is, however, if it isn't `UPPER` the first character and `LOWER` the rest:

```sql
DECLARE @YourString varchar(8000) = 'DOT FOODS , dot foods , CANADA COMPANY, INC CANADA COMPANY, inc';

SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN LEN(SS.value) <= 3 THEN SS.value
                       ELSE UPPER(LEFT(SS.Value,1)) + LOWER(STUFF(SS.Value,1,1,''))
                  END,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SS.ordinal)
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@YourString, ' ',1) SS;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/USpkFdFZ)

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it returns the begging of some strings with lower. Also not sure how to apply this in the function.

Comment: With what you've provided, I don't get that result (see the fiddle), which suggests there's criteria you aren't telling us, @Ace . As for putting it in the function, just assign the `STRING_AGG` expression to your return parameter `@String`, or wrap the above `SELECT` in a subquery in your `RETURN` clause.

Comment: You are right , my bad , i think this will work. Thank you a lot , big help !